# How to QUERY - group SUMed results?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrays

I'm new to query and can't figure out how to get grouped results of sum in two columns.
[image: dataset]
There's data set in the picture of names and points which are in two columns and query formula to sum and group the results for first two columns.

```
=QUERY(AF2:AJ34; "select AG, sum(AH) 
where AG is not null 
group by AG
order by sum(AH) desc
label AG 'Name', sum(AH) 'Points'")
```

How can I get the same result but from both columns of points?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can create a two-columns range with curly brackets, by stacking those two columns: `{AG2:AH;AI2:AJ}`

```
=QUERY({AG2:AH;AI2:AJ}; "select Col1, sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 order by sum(Col2) desc label Col1 'Name', sum(Col2) 'Points'")
```

(PS: you could also use VSTACK instead of curly brackets)

Comment: Hey Martin, that works!!! Cheers, appretiate your help.

Comment: @Jan Please read [What should I do when someone answer my question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)